# Looking for an idiomatic way to build a singly-linked list in Rust iteratively, with a step-by-step debug print?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'd like to iteratively debug print a singly-linked list as it builds, but I can't find a legal way to borrow.

Am I coming at the problem in a way that's too object oriented?
Do I need to abandon safe rust or use RefCell for something so simple?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut list = Some(Box::new(List { val: 0, next: None }));
    let mut current = &mut list;
    for i in 1..10 {
        let next = Box::new(List { val: i, next: None });
        current.as_mut().unwrap().next = Some(next);
        current = &mut current.as_mut().unwrap().next;
        // dbg!(list); Illegal!
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct List {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Box<List>>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your `current` always mutably borrows `list`, but printing `list` requires an immutable borrow. Recall that you can only have either 1 mutable borrow (also sometimes called unique pointer) or multiple immutable borrows (also sometimes called shared pointer) of a value at one time, so you'd have to release `current` before you can print `list`.

This is actually an entire class of problems in dealing with the borrow checker, namely borrowing part of a value is equivalent to borrowing the whole from the compiler's perspective. For the more common needs, there sometimes exists safe abstractions that are implemented using unsafe code - the most well-known example being [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#creating-a-safe-abstraction-over-unsafe-code).

So yes, if we are talking about the more general use case of "obtaining an immutable reference to a value while a part of it is mutably borrowed", you would indeed need unsafe code or [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) (which of course comes at a performance penalty since safety checks are done at runtime).

---

That being said, in your specific case, it is actually possible to ***kind of*** achieve what you want without any performance penalty due to coincidental computation overlap between `Debug` print and getting `list`'s tail.

The key is to understand that `Debug` necessarily has to iterate over the entire list for it to print the entire list. This means if you are willing to forgo using `Debug` and write your own print code instead (this is why I said ***kind of***), you can reuse the iterating that's already being done to obtain a mutable reference to the tail without any additional cost. Again, the existence of this possibility is purely coincidental, so it's likely not very useful outside of this very specific context. I'll show you the code regardless:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut list = List { val: 0, next: None };
    for i in 1..10 {
        let next = Box::new(List { val: i, next: None });
        let tail = list.print_and_get_tail_mut();
        tail.next = Some(next);
    }
}

struct List {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Box<List>>,
}
impl List {
    fn print_and_get_tail_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        let mut print_buffer = String::new();
        let tail = self.print_and_get_tail_mut_impl(&mut print_buffer);
        println!("[{print_buffer}]");
        tail
    }
    fn print_and_get_tail_mut_impl(&mut self, print_buffer: &mut String) -> &mut Self {
        print_buffer.push_str(&format!("{}, ", self.val));
        if self.next.is_none() {
            return self;
        }
        self.next
            .as_mut()
            .unwrap()
            .print_and_get_tail_mut_impl(print_buffer)
    }
}
```

```bash
$ cargo run
[0, ]
[0, 1, ]
[0, 1, 2, ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ]
```

Note that this does not print the newly added tail node because print happens before append. But you can modify `print_and_get_tail_mut` into something like `push_and_print` rather trivially.

Comment: And finally as a sidenote, it's almost never a good idea to use linked lists in practise. The theoretical efficiency gains are usually drastically outweighed by the optimisations available only to array-based solutions. See [here](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/).

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed impossible.

You can do that by paying a performance penalty of finding the tail from the first element each time:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut list = Some(Box::new(List { val: 0, next: None }));
    for i in 1..10 {
        let next = Box::new(List { val: i, next: None });
        let mut current = &mut list;
        while let Some(v) = current {
            current = &mut v.next;
        }
        *current = Some(next);
        dbg!(&list);
    }
}
```

Or by just printing only the newly appended element:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut list = Some(Box::new(List { val: 0, next: None }));
    let mut current = &mut list;
    for i in 1..10 {
        let next = Box::new(List { val: i, next: None });
        current.as_mut().unwrap().next = Some(next);
        current = &mut current.as_mut().unwrap().next;
        dbg!(&current);
    }
}
```